# Training BERT (bert-base-uncased) for a Custom Dataset for Multi-label task

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, training-data

I am trying to train BERT to a custom dataset with the labels shown in the code to be deployed to hugging face afterwards. It runs into errors regarding the performance metrics like this:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f777547e5264> in <cell line: 135>()
    133 
    134 # Train the model
--> 135 trainer.train()
    136 
    137 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   3163         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   3164 
-> 3165     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)
   3166 
   3167 

RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long
```

I've created a Pytorch dataset, that looks like this:

```py
class ToxicData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels=None):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        if self.labels is not None:
            item["labels"] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.float)  # Convert labels to Float
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings["input_ids"])

# Define label columns
label_columns = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

train_dataset = ToxicData(train_encodings, train_df[label_columns].values)
validation_dataset = ToxicData(validation_encodings, val_df[label_columns].values)
test_dataset = ToxicData(test_encodings, test_df[label_columns].values)
```

And I'm using this model:

```
# Create the model
model = BertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
  model_checkpoint, num_labels=6)
```

Here's the full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer, BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer, BertPreTrainedModel
from transformers.modeling_outputs import SequenceClassifierOutput
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss

train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test_labels_df = pd.read_csv("test_labels.csv")

# Merging the test data with test labels
test_df = test_df.merge(test_labels_df, on="id")

# Filtering out rows with -1 labels in the test dataset so that we only
#only evaluate your model on comments that have valid labels and are relevant for performance evaluation
test_df = test_df[(test_df.toxic != -1) & (test_df.severe_toxic != -1) & (test_df.obscene != -1) & (test_df.threat != -1) & (test_df.insult != -1) & (test_df.identity_hate != -1)]

# Splitting the train data into trainining and validation sets
train_df, val_df = train_test_split(train_df, test_size=0.1, random_state=34)

model_checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
#Tokenizing the data based on the bert model 
def tokenize_data(df):
    return tokenizer(df["comment_text"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=500)

train_encodings = tokenize_data(train_df)
validation_encodings = tokenize_data(val_df)
test_encodings = tokenize_data(test_df)

#Using PyTorch datasets from the tokenized data

class ToxicData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels=None):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        if self.labels is not None:
            item["labels"] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.float)  # Convert labels to Float
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings["input_ids"])

# Define label columns
label_columns = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

train_dataset = ToxicData(train_encodings, train_df[label_columns].values)
validation_dataset = ToxicData(validation_encodings, val_df[label_columns].values)
test_dataset = ToxicData(test_encodings, test_df[label_columns].values)


#Fine-tuning and training BERT to our dataset

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")



#Function to create the model
class BertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification(BertForSequenceClassification):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None, position_ids=None, head_mask=None, inputs_embeds=None, labels=None, output_attentions=None, output_hidden_states=None, return_dict=None):
        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, position_ids=position_ids, head_mask=head_mask, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds, output_attentions=output_attentions, output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states, return_dict=return_dict)

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1, self.num_labels))

        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return SequenceClassifierOutput(loss=loss, logits=logits, hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states, attentions=outputs.attentions)


# Create the model
model = BertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=6)
model.to(device)
#Metrics for the Trainer()
def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    print("Pred.predictions:", pred.predictions)
    preds = pred.predictions.round()
    precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, preds, average='weighted')
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {
        'accuracy': acc,
        'f1': f1,
        'precision': precision,
        'recall': recall
    }


# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="output",
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="logs",
    logging_steps=1,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="f1",
)

# Create the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, usually a code dump and error code will lead to question closing due to being unclear, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Scroll down to the **The Trainer** section.

---

## In Long

Lets walkthrough the code to understand each part of your code.

## The Data

First the data, I'm guessing here but given that you are doing:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test_labels_df = pd.read_csv("test_labels.csv")
test_df = test_df.merge(test_labels_df, on="id")
...

tokenizer(df["comment_text"].tolist(), ...)

...

# Define label columns
label_columns = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

train_dataset = ToxicData(train_encodings, train_df[label_columns].values)

...
```

your csv file data would look something like something like:

```
id,comment_text,toxic,severe_toxic,obscene,threat,insult,identity_hate
1234,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
567,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
```

It looks like it's coming from:

- https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge (which is usually use as a homework exercise)
- https://github.com/unitaryai/detoxify

If you have a csv file, you can actually use `load_dataset` from https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


sample = """id,comment_text,toxic,severe_toxic,obscene,threat,insult,identity_hate
1234,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
567,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
4576,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
821,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
27324,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
132,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
"""

with open('sample.csv', 'w') as fout:
    print(sample, file=fout)
    

ds = load_dataset('csv', data_files="sample.csv")

train_ids, dev_ids = train_test_split(range(len(ds['train'])))

ds['dev'] = ds['train'][dev_ids]
ds['train'] = ds['train'][train_ids]

ds
```

[out]:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: {'id': [567, 821, 1234, 4576], 'comment_text': ['What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.', 'What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.', 'This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me', 'This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me'], 'toxic': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'severe_toxic': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'obscene': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'threat': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'insult': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'identity_hate': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
    dev: {'id': [132, 27324], 'comment_text': ['What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.', 'This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me'], 'toxic': [1, 1], 'severe_toxic': [0, 1], 'obscene': [0, 1], 'threat': [1, 0], 'insult': [0, 0], 'identity_hate': [0, 0]}
})
```

##### StackOverflow Tip:

> When asking a machine learning on SO, it's best to give a sample of how your dataset look like, particularly show (a) a sample of the raw file (b) how you want to read it, (c) what object do you want to read it into

---

## The Tokenizer

Next on the tokenizer, there's a lot of imports but I think only the `AutoTokenizer` is used, so instead of doing this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer, BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer, BertPreTrainedModel
from transformers.modeling_outputs import SequenceClassifierOutput

model_checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

def tokenize_data(df):
    return tokenizer(df["comment_text"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=500)

train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test_labels_df = pd.read_csv("test_labels.csv")

# Merging the test data with test labels
test_df = test_df.merge(test_labels_df, on="id")
train_encodings = tokenize_data(train_df)
```

You can simply do:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

tokenizer([
  "This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me"
  "What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&."
])
```

---

## The Model

From your code, this is the main meat of the model:

```
#Function to create the model
class BertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification(BertForSequenceClassification):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None, position_ids=None, head_mask=None, inputs_embeds=None, labels=None, output_attentions=None, output_hidden_states=None, return_dict=None):
        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, position_ids=position_ids, head_mask=head_mask, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds, output_attentions=output_attentions, output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states, return_dict=return_dict)

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1, self.num_labels))

        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return SequenceClassifierOutput(loss=loss, logits=logits, hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states, attentions=outputs.attentions)


# Create the model
model = BertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=6)
model.to(device)
```

Breaking it down a little, you are trying to:

1. Subclass the `BertForSequenceClassification` object
2. Replace the loss function to `BCEWithLogitsLoss`
3. Output `SequenceClassifierOutput` object in the model's forward function

At this point, after understanding what is required/desired for the model, I usually do this: https://www.google.com/search?q=BertForSequenceClassification+%22BCEWithLogitsLoss%22+%22SequenceClassifierOutput%22

And it'll lead to several links:

i. The source code from the Github repository and we see that there is BCE loss already in the code if you specify the label types, see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1517

ii. A nice tutorial on colab that does something similar to what you're expecting https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/BERT/Fine_tuning_BERT_(and_friends)_for_multi_label_text_classification.ipynb

iii. This question itself, [Training BERT (bert-base-uncased) for a Custom Dataset for Multi-label task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065460/training-bert-for-a-custom-dataset)

#### The Problem Type

From link (i), the code, we see:

```
class BertForSequenceClassification(BertPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        ...

    def forward(
        self, ...)
        return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict

        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            ...
        )

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            if self.config.problem_type is None:
                if self.num_labels == 1:
                    self.config.problem_type = "regression"
                elif self.num_labels > 1 and (labels.dtype == torch.long or labels.dtype == torch.int):
                    self.config.problem_type = "single_label_classification"
                else:
                    self.config.problem_type = "multi_label_classification"

            if self.config.problem_type == "regression":
                loss_fct = MSELoss()
                if self.num_labels == 1:
                    loss = loss_fct(logits.squeeze(), labels.squeeze())
                else:
                    loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
            elif self.config.problem_type == "single_label_classification":
                loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
            elif self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
                loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
        if not return_dict:
            output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return SequenceClassifierOutput(
            loss=loss,
            logits=logits,
            hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states,
            attentions=outputs.attentions,
        )
```

Particularly, we see:

```
self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
                loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
                loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
```

In that case, you can actually initialize the `BertForSequenceClassification` class without subclassing it, since it satisfy the (1), (2) and (3) points you wanted.

Thus, in code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-uncased", 
     problem_type="multi_label_classification", 
     ...
)
```

And to specify the labels:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

label_columns = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

label2id = {label:i for i, label in enumerate(label_columns)}
id2label {i:labels for i, label in enumerate(label_columns)}

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-uncased", 
    problem_type="multi_label_classification", 
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id
)
```

##### StackOverflow Tip:

> When asking a Huggingface transformers questions, it's best to tell (a) what models are you using (in this case `bert-base-uncased`, (b) what's your `import transformers; transformers.__version` on the machine (c) what machine are you using, CPU or GPU, local or cloud, etc.

##### StackOverflow Tip:

> When asking a Huggingface transformers question, don't just paste the code and error message, try to explain what you've tried to understand the error message and what is your expected output / desired goal, e.g.  (1) , (2) and (3) listed above

---

## The Metric

When we initialize the `Trainer` object in Huggingface, we'll need the `compute_metrics` function, e.g.

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=ds_train,
    eval_dataset=ds_valid,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

Taking the code from:

- https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/BERT/Fine_tuning_BERT_(and_friends)_for_multi_label_text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=797b2WHJqUgZ
- https://jesusleal.io/2021/04/21/Longformer-multilabel-classification/

We can do this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, accuracy_score
from transformers import EvalPrediction
import torch
    
def multi_label_metrics(predictions, labels, threshold=0.5):
    # first, apply sigmoid on predictions which are of shape (batch_size, num_labels)
    sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    probs = sigmoid(torch.Tensor(predictions))
    # next, use threshold to turn them into integer predictions
    y_pred = np.zeros(probs.shape)
    y_pred[np.where(probs >= threshold)] = 1
    # finally, compute metrics
    y_true = labels
    f1_micro_average = f1_score(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, average='micro')
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'micro')
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    # return as dictionary
    metrics = {'f1': f1_micro_average,
               'roc_auc': roc_auc,
               'accuracy': accuracy}
    return metrics

def compute_metrics(p: EvalPrediction):
    preds = p.predictions[0] if isinstance(p.predictions, 
            tuple) else p.predictions
    result = multi_label_metrics(
        predictions=preds, 
        labels=p.label_ids)
    return result
```

This is a little more complicated than the one you have in your code because the computation of the labels is offloaded till the `compute_metrics` here but in your code you are preloading it as a label processing step.

---

## The Trainer

The details in the above section gives you a general idea of how to approach the code debugging and the concepts without going into the nitty-gritties.

The code snippet below works with a kinks/hacks in the code that's not fully described in the parts above but that's because I think those are not the main concepts of how the ML model works but just syntax/library requirements issues.

Finally, to put everything above together,

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np


from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, accuracy_score
from transformers import EvalPrediction
import torch

from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

import os
os.environ["WANDB_DISABLED"] = "true"


sample = """id,text,toxic,severe_toxic,obscene,threat,insult,identity_hate
1234,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
567,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
4576,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
821,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
27324,"This is a foo bar sentence, #$%^&* me",1,1,1,0,0,0
132,"What the *&^%^%, this is a $#%^&.",1,0,0,1,0,0
"""

with open('sample.csv', 'w') as fout:
    print(sample, file=fout)
    

ds = load_dataset('csv', data_files="sample.csv")

label_columns = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

ds['train'] = ds['train'].map(lambda x: tokenizer(x['text']))
ds['train'] = ds['train'].map(lambda x: {"labels": torch.tensor([float(x[l]) for l in label_columns])})

train_ids, dev_ids = train_test_split(range(len(ds['train'])))

ds['dev'] = Dataset.from_dict(ds['train'][dev_ids])
ds['train'] = Dataset.from_dict(ds['train'][train_ids])

label2id = {label:i for i, label in enumerate(label_columns)}
id2label = {i:label for i, label in enumerate(label_columns)}

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-uncased", 
    problem_type="multi_label_classification", 
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id
) 



def multi_label_metrics(predictions, labels, threshold=0.5):
    # first, apply sigmoid on predictions which are of shape (batch_size, num_labels)
    sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    probs = sigmoid(torch.Tensor(predictions))
    # next, use threshold to turn them into integer predictions
    y_pred = np.zeros(probs.shape)
    y_pred[np.where(probs >= threshold)] = 1
    # finally, compute metrics
    y_true = labels
    f1_micro_average = f1_score(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, average='micro')
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'micro')
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    # return as dictionary
    metrics = {'f1': f1_micro_average,
               'roc_auc': roc_auc,
               'accuracy': accuracy}
    return metrics

def compute_metrics(p: EvalPrediction):
    preds = p.predictions[0] if isinstance(p.predictions, 
            tuple) else p.predictions
    result = multi_label_metrics(
        predictions=preds, 
        labels=p.label_ids)
    return result


# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="output",
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    warmup_steps=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="logs",
    logging_steps=1,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="f1",
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=ds['train'],
    eval_dataset=ds['dev'],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

trainer.train()
```