# Can we train Sentence transformer model for Sequence classification

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

Can we use a fine-tuned Sentence Transformer model for fine-tuning `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`?

1. I have a Fine tuned Sentence transformer model which has pooling layers also.
2. Now, I take this model and again fine tune on AutoModelForSequenceClassification() for binary classes.

I only get this warning:

> Some weights of `BertForSequenceClassification` were not initialized from the model checkpoint at sent_tranf_model/ and are newly initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']
> You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.

Code:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sent_tranf_model/")
NUM_LABELS = len(idx_to_label)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ssent_tranf_model/",num_labels = NUM_LABELS)
```

Is it okay to do this?

Comment: The code answer needed will depends on what dataset you have and how you want to train it and which model you want to finetune for the classification task. If you add those information into the question, it will help us help you better.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065460/training-bert-bert-base-uncased-for-a-custom-dataset-for-multi-label-task

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do that. The warning you are seeing is typical when you start fine-tuning a pre-trained model with a classification layer on top, like `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`.

The warning is saying that some weights (specifically those in the `classifier` layer) are not being initialized from the pre-trained model. This is expected, because your Sentence Transformer model did not have a classification layer, so it doesn't have pretrained weights for this layer. Instead, these weights are being initialized randomly, hence the warning.

Therefore, you should indeed train this model on your downstream task before you use it for prediction or inference, as the warning suggests. This is because the 'classifier' layer's weights are currently random and would produce meaningless outputs.